# Emacs: disable automatic file search in ido mode

Tags: emacs, ido-mode

I use ido mode. Here is how I set in `.emacs`

```
(require 'ido)
(setq ido-enable-flex-matching t)
(setq ido-everywhere t)
(ido-mode t)
```

When I open a file, I do C-x C-f `my_file` and if it doesn't exist in current directory, emacs will try to search for it in other recent used directories in about a second. However, most of the time I was just trying to create new files. I had to type the file name really fast and then C-j to confirm it. How can I stop ido from doing this?

Comment: alias 'open new file' as some key other then C-x C-f (M-x find-file is the right name of the action)

Comment: @user2141046 @woodings From `ido-find-file` you can just hit `C-x C-f` again to drop down into the traditional `find-file` interface

Comment: @assem I don't want to fall back to normal `find-file`. I need `ido` but not search in other directories.

Comment: @assem It's just `C-f`.

Comment: @abo-abo oh, yes indeed it is, thanks

Comment: I think this is the most annoying feature of all time.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found an easy solution:

```el
(setq ido-auto-merge-delay-time 9)
```

The time here is in seconds. I could set a very large number to completely disable this feature.

Comment: or set `ido-auto-merge-work-directories-length` to `-1` to disable

Comment: @woodings, this problem really annoyed me for a while when I use ido, finally, I decided to search the solution. Before I got this page, I found that when you using ido, you can just use C-f to go back to normal mode instead of ido, but your solution seems better. Thank you!

Answer (score 42):

The following will completely disable the feature:

```
(setq ido-auto-merge-work-directories-length -1)
```

I've never seen any value in it, so disabling it completely might make sense for a lot of people.

Comment: M-x customize-variable ido-auto-merge-work-directories-length

Answer (score 16):

Here is another option using Ido:

1. Type <kbd>C-x C-f</kbd> as usual.
2. Find the directory you want to create the new file in using Ido search.
3. At any moment type <kbd>C-f</kbd> again, and Emacs will go back to the old `find-file` functionality.

You can then type the file name you want and Emacs will create a new buffer. So, if you type <kbd>C-x C-f</kbd> <kbd>C-f</kbd> `file_name` <kbd>RET</kbd> it will create a buffer called `file_name` temporarily in the current directory.